# Form doesn't refresh in Powershell GUI application (Enable/Disable Text boxes doesn't work)

Tags: winforms, powershell, user-interface, active-directory

i am writing a script which reads the user details from active directory, it reads users samid and pull all his details in text  boxes to display; here i am using a radio button to enable/disable all those textboes. That is radio button switches between 2 modes, readmode/writemode which enables and disables those text boxes so that they can be edited and changes can be committed.

Here is the issue, by default readmode radio button is checked and every text box is disabled, when i check the write mode button , everything gets enabled , but it stays there. when i check the readmode button again , it doesn't disable those boxes ; i tried form refresh , but it didn't work; please let me know if any alternatives.

```
function ReadAD( $object )
{
$TextBox2.Enabled = "False"
$TextBox3.Enabled = "False"
$TextBox4.Enabled = "False"
$TextBox5.Enabled = "False"
$TextBox6.Enabled = "False"
$TextBox7.Enabled = "False"
$TextBox8.Enabled = "False"
$TextBox9.Enabled = "False"
$RichTextBox1.Enabled = "False"
$Button4.Visible = "False"
$form1.refresh()
}

function WriteAD( $object )
{
$TextBox2.Enabled = "False"
$TextBox3.Enabled = "False"
$TextBox4.Enabled = "False"
$TextBox5.Enabled = "False"
$TextBox6.Enabled = "False"
$TextBox7.Enabled = "False"
$TextBox8.Enabled = "False"
$TextBox9.Enabled = "False"
$RichTextBox1.Enabled = "False"
$Button4.Visible = "False"
$form1.refresh()
}
```

Comment: It didnt work , still those boces are stale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Enabled` and `Visible` properties takes a `bool`, not a `string`. `bool` in PowerShell is `$true` and `$false`. Try this:

```
$TextBox9.Enabled = $false
$RichTextBox1.Enabled = $false
$Button4.Visible = $false
```

There's no need to refresh, doevents etc. At least everything works perfectly when I test it by only changing the `bool` value like above.